# How to get rid of 0 numbering in list of to do and table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, numbering

Here is the code I am using

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}




\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\color{blue}}{\faBook}{1em}{\thesection.}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\color{black}}{\faAngleRight}{1em}{\thesubsection.}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\pgfornament[width=2cm]{88}}


\begin{document}

\title{Hello All}
\author{XYZ}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\listoftodos

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}




\end{document}
```

I get 0.To Do list and 0. Content. How do I get rid of this and just have 1.Introduction?

Comment: I think you may have too many packages loaded for your MWE. Try loading only the packages you need first. The issue is probably with one of the loaded packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- I removed the packages that are not needed for this example

You define the format of section and subsection with:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\color{blue}}{\faBook}{1em}{\thesection.}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\color{black}}{\faAngleRight}{1em}{\thesubsection.}
```

Because the headings "Todo list" and "Contents" are placed as `section*`, they are affected by this. If you put both `\titleformat` lines below the `\tableofcontents` it only affects the following sections and subsections.

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhead[C]{\pgfornament[width=2cm]{88}}

\begin{document}

\title{Hello All}
\author{XYZ}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\listoftodos

\tableofcontents

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries\color{blue}}{\faBook}{1em}{\thesection.}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\color{black}}{\faAngleRight}{1em}{\thesubsection.}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```